# How to parametrize SQL query, by passing multiple value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a SQL query, in where clause "MID = 123". I want to use a parameter for the VALUE and pass multiple values.

Example: now I am passing one VALUE of 123, but I want to pass multiple value like `123, 124, 125` etc. from which the SQL query will take values one by one and pass those to the `where` clause, and produce the result one by one, like first use `value = 123`, get the result, when use `value = 124` and get results, and last use `value = 125` to get results.

I need help with this parameter.

It will be great if we don't change the SQL query but we can parameter the where clause.

NOTE: I am using SQL Developer.

SQL query:

```
SELECT
    'ABC' AS COLUMN_NAME,
    (CASE 
        WHEN to_char(count(ABC)) > 1 
              AND to_char(max(ABC)) = to_char(min(ABC)) 
              AND to_char(count(ABC)) = count(*) 
              AND to_char(max(ABC)) IS NULL 
           THEN 'same' 
           ELSE 'Diff'
     END) AS COMPARISON_VALUE,
    (CASE 
        WHEN to_char(COUNT(ABC)) = 1 OR to_char(min(ABC)) IS NULL 
           THEN 'No Values' 
           ELSE to_char(max(ABC)) 
     END) AS TRANSACTION1,
    to_char(min(ABC)) AS TRANSACTION2
FROM 
    ADVICES 
WHERE 
    MID = '123';
```

Comment: SQL Server <> Oracle. What are you *really* using? That statement above is clearly not T-SQL; so I *assume* the latter.

Comment: Hi Larnu i am using ORACLE.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I edited your post for improving query format, I hope you  don't mind :)

Comment: Thanks Sammie, it's looks better now :)

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be useful. You probably just need `or` and `group by` (and `order by`) but your description isn't clear. Also, why are you using `to_char()` inside your case expressions? And if `mid` is a number column then you should compare it with a number rather than a string.

Comment: Also, where do you want to pass multiple values from - someone typing them in your SQL client, or an application running your query, or are they coming from another table?

Comment: HI Alex, i am trying to parameter the where clause, for which i want to fetch parameter data from text or CSV should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to specify the test data in a WITH clause and feed it to the query via an outer join.  We include the test value as the first column in the result set.  This means that every row in the result set will have the associated test value.

```
WITH testdata(testval) AS
(
  SELECT '123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '124' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '125' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    testdata.testval,
    ...
    ...
FROM 
    ADVICES, testdata
WHERE 
    MID (+) = testdata.testval;
```

> ...i am trying to parameter the where clause, for which i want to fetch
>   parameter data from text or CSV should be fine.

Alternatively, `testdata` could be a table that's loaded from a CSV file with test values.

Answer (score 0):

You may pass a CSV and use `LIKE`.

```
where ','||:var||','  like '%,'||MID||',%'
```

Example using HR schema

```
var myvar VARCHAR2 
exec :myvar := '101,102,103' --parameter
select employee_id,department_id from employees where 
     ','||:myvar||','  like '%,'||employee_id||',%';
```

Result

```
EMPLOYEE_ID DEPARTMENT_ID
----------- -------------
        101            90
        102            90
        103            60
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your WHERE clause like the following:

```
WHERE MID IN
(SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('YOUR_VALUE', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
FROM
    DUAL
CONNECT BY
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('YOUR_VALUE', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL);
```

For checking the solution:

```
-- With multiple values
DEFINE YOUR_VALUE= '123,124,125';
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('&YOUR_VALUE', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
FROM
    DUAL
CONNECT BY
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('&YOUR_VALUE', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL);

-- OUTPUT --

REGEXP_SUBS
-----------
123
124
125


-- With single value
DEFINE YOUR_VALUE = '123';
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('&YOUR_VALUE', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
FROM
    DUAL
CONNECT BY
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('&YOUR_VALUE', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;

-- OUTPUT --

REGEXP_SUBS
-----------
123
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score -1):

You can change your where clause to -

```
WHERE 
MID IN (YOUR_PARAMETER);
```

When you will pass multiple values, it will simply converted to `OR` condition and will fetch the results.